# MaxCDN + Magento Developer> Merge CSS 404 error

Tags: magento-1.9, cdn

I just setup my store to Use MAX CDN.
The merged CSS files does not load when the setting is ON.
The **System > Configuration > Advanced > Developer> Merge CSS Files** is set to Yes.

If I Set the Merge CSS Files to No.
All the CSS files load from CDN.

I've tried toggling the settings and Clearing the Cache. 
Also setup CORS to set "*"

Answer (score 0):

Merge css load from media folder so you have to move your media folder to cdn as well . and in media url give your cdn url at system->config

Example shown below url

[Integrating Magento with Amazon’s CDN Cloudfront](https://www.thirdandgrove.com/integrating-magento-with-amazons-cdn-cloudfront)

Comment: Thanks for your input. 
The Files are there in the MAX CDN - but they all are of 0 bytes. ( The combined CSS files from /media/css and /media/secure_css/)